# Upload druid and superset image to ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, apache-superset, amazon-ecr

I have created a docker image for DRUID and Superset, now I want to push these images to ECR. and start an ECS to run these containers. What I have done is I have created the images by running docker-compose up on my YML file. Now when I type `docker image ls` i can see multiple images running in them.

1. I have created an aws account and created a repository. They have provided the push command and I push the superset into the ECR for start. (Didn't push any dependancy)
2. I created a cluster in AWS, in one configuration step if provided custom port 8088. I don't know what and why they ask these port for.
3. Then I created a load balancer with the default configuration
4. After some time I could see the container status turned running
5. I navigated to the public ip i mentioned with port 8088 and could see superset running

Now I have two problems

1. It always shows login error in a superset
2. It stops automatically after some time and restarts after that and this cycle continues.

Should I create different ECR repos and push all the dependencies to ECR before creating a cluster in ECS?

[image]

Comment: did you provide the healthcheck endpoint correctly??

Comment: @Infamous I am completely new to this stacks, where shall i put it, if you don't mind what does this healthcheck endpoint do.

Comment: I did a simple spring boot app which just returns a string and containerised it and uploaded it into ECR and created an ECS , it also get stopped after 2 min

Comment: I believe the reason behind the restart after few mins is because the health check fails for superset after the grace period  you configured in the Load balancer

Comment: What should i do to enable this health check?

Comment: You need to have an endpoint which acts as a health check that returns 2xx series status code to the ALB when it does the periodic health check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204727/discussion-between-infamous-and-george-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

For the service going up and down.  Since you mentioned you have an LB associated with the service, you may have an issue with the health check configuration.
If the health check fails consecutively a number of times, ecs will kill it and re-start it.